# Preserve New Lines when Using the PHP DOMDocument() Class

Tags: php, newline, domdocument

I have HTML that looks like this when you view the source:

### Original HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

But after I do:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->saveHTML();
```

My source code turns to this:

### New HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

How can I preserve new lines and white space when using the PHP DOMDocument() class and its methods?

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate - the other question is about how to pretty-print a document that has been built dynamically, but this question is about how to preserve the layout of a document built from an HTML string.  The answer may be similar but the use-case is completely different.

Answer (score 2):

To preserve the whitespace, try something along these lines:

```
$dom=new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->formatOutput=false;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace=true;

$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->standalone=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->recover=true;
```

There are a few other propertes you can set - you'll find them in the manual

Comment: I tried all of your suggestions but it's still stripping all of my newlines.

Comment: I found that having flags on the loadHTML function made this not work, for example: `$dom->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);` didn't work, while `$dom->loadHTML($content);` *did* work. In fact, preserving the white space is turned on by default.

Comment: did you make it work?